# Possibility to discard region in multi region YugabyteDB cluster

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

A question that came in my recent large-scale tests, say that I have a multi-regional cluster and I lose a complete region, with volumes and everything, say the thing was obliterated by a meteorite.

Is there any way to tell the complete system `hey, this region is never coming back, please discard it and continue working`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not available with a single command. Say it's a 3 region cluster. You can't "normally" continue working because you're down to 2 regions. The cluster will be online, but since all those nodes are lost you'll have to add new nodes to the region to have 3 available regions again.

This can be done by discarding all nodes in the down region one by one and adding new nodes to the same region.

For a step by step guide check this doc: https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/manage/change-cluster-config/